# Changing multiple strings in column inside a function tidyverse style

Tags: r, string, function, dplyr, tidyverse

For the following data frame

```
> df <- data.frame(Country = c("Republic of Ireland", "United Kingdom", "United States of America"))
# Country
# <chr>
# Republic of Ireland               
# United Kingdom                
# United States of America
```

Is there a way for me to change the Country names by using a function (tidyverse style). I also want to be able to reference a specific column in the data frame.

This is what I have done so far:

```
# c("Old name", "new name")
name_change = list(c("Republic of Ireland", "Ireland"), 
                   c("United Kingdom", "UK"),
                   c("Russia Moscow", "Russia"),
                   c("United States of America", "USA"))


name_change_func <- function(vec, data = c2, df_col = Country){
  # Expecting vec c("Old name", "new name")
  old_n <- vec[1]
  new_n <- vec[2]
  data %>% 
    mutate(!!df_col = gsub(old_n, new_n, !!df_col ))
}

map_df(name_change, ~name_change_func(.x)) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  filter(row_number(Country) == 1)
```

And this does not work, but if we change !!df_col to Country directly, it will work (kind of, will get duplicate names that need to be filtered away and we are not really changing names so much as adding rows).

Is there a way to fix this? To be able to use a function argument as column inside the function.
Bonus points if you know a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a named vector to replace instead which can be used in `str_replace_all`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#c("Old name" = "new name")
name_change = c("Republic of Ireland" = "Ireland", 
                 "United Kingdom" = "UK",
                 "Russia Moscow" = "Russia",
                 "United States of America" = "USA")

df %>% mutate(new_country = str_replace_all(Country, name_change))

#                   Country new_country
#1      Republic of Ireland     Ireland
#2           United Kingdom          UK
#3 United States of America         USA
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is `case_when` within the `tidyverse`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Country = c("Republic of Ireland", "United Kingdom", "United States of America"))

df <- 
  df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(NewCountry = 
    case_when(
      Country == "Republic of Ireland" ~ "Ireland",
      Country == "United States of America" ~ "US",
      Country == "United Kingdom" ~ "UK",
      Country == "Russia Moscow" ~ "Russia"
    )
  )
#                    Country NewCountry
# 1      Republic of Ireland    Ireland
# 2           United Kingdom         UK
# 3 United States of America         US
```